# git-svn clone svn repository, fetch and merge only particular files into git project

Tags: git, svn

I want to set up WordPress testing with PHPUnit. The [Automated Testing](http://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/automated-testing/) guide of the handbook states that the steps necessary to run the tests are:

```
 1. Standard PHPUnit install
 2. svn co http://develop.svn.wordpress.org/trunk/ wordpress-develop
 3. cd wordpress-develop
 4. phpunit
```

I want to incorporate `./wp-config-test.php`, `./tests/`, and `./phpunit.xml.dist` from the SVN repository (in point nª2) into the project's master branch, and be able to fetch and merge future updates to these files/directories from it's origin to the project.

My current project's configuration is a WordPress installation tracked by git with `master` and `stage` branches.

```
ajf:leadsconsite alain$ git branch
  master
* stage
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You write about "the SVN repository" and "the project's master branch". Do you have two repositories, one SVN and one git repo? Why? And what do they contain? Please edit your question.

Comment: What information do you need? I added some lines, let me know what else you would like me to add.

Comment: Thanks, that makes things clearer.More questions: Why do you want to run the tests? Aren't they only for people working on WordPress itself? And do you plan to change the tests? If not, what is the point of pulling the tests into your repository, instead of just downloading and running them?

Comment: My intention is to incorporate WordPress core unit tests, and if possible, extend them with my own tests to drive theme & plugin development for a multisite install. I don't plan on changing existing tests, and I could download them -and probably will if the solution to this question is extremely complicated-, but I was hoping I could have those tied up to their remote in order to pull changes together with the WordPress updates I make

Answer (score 0):

*I'm a bit late answering, but maybe it helps someone else.*

Unit tests are generally quite closely tied to the code they test, so separating them from the main WordPress code probably does not make sense.

That said, I think you have two options:

1. Copy the test from the WP repo, from the version that best matches the WP code in your repository.
2. *or* Clone the whole WP repo (including production code and tests), and port (rebase) your changes to WP on top of that. In other words, make your repository a fork of the main WP repo.

Approach 1) is probably easier initally, but means that fetching upstream changes to the tests will be a manual process (fetching the diff to your last import, and merging it in). However, fetching upstream changes may require manual work anyway, because you will probably have to adapt the new/changed tests to your version of the code. So this may not be too bad.

2) is arguably more elegant in the longer run, and allows you to use git's mechanisms for the update (merge or rebase). However, the inital setup is more cumbersome, as you will need to rework your current repository to be based on the main WP repository.

---

Personally, I'd probably use approach 2), but it's up to you what tradeoff you prefer.